# Return all records within 3 month period (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, datetime

So what I want to achieve is to return data from within the last 3 months.
My current MySQL query is as follows:

`SELECT MONTH(service_date_time) AS month, SUM(service_price) AS total FROM appointments WHERE user_id = 1 AND service_date_time >= last_day(now()) + INTERVAL 1 day - INTERVAL 3 month GROUP BY YEAR(service_date_time), MONTH(service_date_time)`

My table appointments contains data from January and May and `service_date_time` is a `date_time` field.

The problem I'm having is that it returns 2 rows, one row totaling the price for January and one row totaling the price for May. The row for May shouldn't be returned since it is not within the past three months.

Anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting all records that are greater than the given date, If you want all the records up to now you'll have to ask for a range for example:

```
WHERE service_date_time BETWEEN (LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND NOW()
```

this would limit the records & give you from 3 months ago till now